# Python Nested loops: printed seats

Tags: python

Given rows and cols, print a list of all seats in a theater. Rows are numbered, columns lettered, as in 1A or 3E. Print a space after each seat, including after the last. 
Ex: `num_rows = 2` and `num_cols = 3` prints:
1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3
c1 = 1
while c1 <= num_rows:
    c2 = 'A'
    while c2 <= 'C':
        print('%s%s' % (c1, c2), end=' ')
        c2 = chr(ord(c2) + 1)
    c1 += 1
print()
```

Output returns correctly when I test with 2 rows and 3 columns or with 5 rows and 3 columns. However, when I test with 0 columns, it returns "1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C 3A 3B 3C 4A 4B 4C 5A 5B 5C" when it should return nothing. I tried changing c2 = 'A' into c2 = num_cols, but didn't change anything.

Comment: I think your problem lays in the line `while c2 <= 'C':`, you're iterating over 3 columns always...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"""    c2 = 'A'
while c2 <= 'C':"""
```

I think the problem is here. Counting the alphabet would need an assigned value like you have 'C' but if you wanted to iterate through the alphabet with more or less columns you would need to assign a number to the maximum instead of the character. (The uppercase alphabetical assignment should only work if columns are between range(1,27))Try the following:

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

rows = 1                       #create a number to start counting from for rows
while rows <= num_rows:        #start iterating through number of rows
    cols = 1                   #create a number to start counting from for columns
    alpha = 'A'                #starting point for alphabet
    while cols <= num_cols:                    #iterates through number of columns
        print('%s%s' % (rows, alpha), end=' ')
        cols +=1                               #number of columns needs to increase
        alpha = chr(ord(alpha) + 1)            #alphabet needs to increase
    rows += 1                                  #number of rows needs to increase
print()                                         

"""This is my very first attempt. Please let me know if my code can be cleaner and more readable"""
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't making use of `num_cols` but instead hard-coding column `C`. You should make the upper bound of the column based on `num_cols`.

Change:

```
while c2 <= 'C':
```

to:

```
while c2 < chr(ord('A') + num_cols):
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do I think first of

```
import itertools
print(' '.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('12', 'ABC')))
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop here could help ease the solution and optimize ouputs

```
rows = 2
columns = 3
l = ['a','b','c']

for i in range(1, rows +1):
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
        print('{}{} '.format(i, l[j-1]), end='')
# 1a 1b 1c 2a 2b 2c 

columns = 0
# No output
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cleanest, but it makes the most sense to me:

```
num_rows = 2
num_cols = 3

letter1 = '1'
letter2 = 'A'

for row in range(num_rows): # sets maximum changes to letter1.
   letter2 = 'A' # makes sure letter2 starts over after the inner loop first finishes.
   for col in range(num_cols): # sets maximum changes to letter2.
      print(letter1 + letter2, end=' ') # Print before incrementing letter2.
      letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1) # converts 'A' to its unicode value, increments it by one, then converts it back to a letter.
   letter1 = chr(ord(letter1) + 1) # only runs after the inner loop is done to increment letter1 for the next loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_row = 2
num_col = 3


i = 1
if num_rows and num_cols > 0:
    while i <= num_rows:    
        seat = 'A'
        while seat <= 'C':
            print('%s%s' %(i,seat), end=" ")
            seat = chr(ord(seat)+1)
        i +=1
print()
```

"Output returns correctly when I test with 2 rows and 3 columns or with 5 rows and 3 columns. However, when I test with 0 columns, it returns "1A 1B 1C 2A 2B 2C 3A 3B 3C 4A 4B 4C 5A 5B 5C" when it should return nothing. I tried changing c2 = 'A' into c2 = num_cols, but didn't change anything." Add an if statement to make sure there are existing chairs. If there isn't a column or row than their isn't a chair

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(num_rows):
    letter = "A"
    num = i+1 #initially 0, so making it 0 + 1 .. and so on
    
    for j in range(num_cols):
        
        print('{}{}'.format(num,letter), end= ' ')
        letter =chr(ord(letter)+1)  #getting the unicode of the letter and incrementing it and changing back to ASCII character
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

row = 1    # establish start point to count rows
for i in range(num_rows):  # iterate num_rows 
    seat = 'A'  # establish start point to count cols
    for j in range(num_cols): # iterate num_cols
        print('{}{}'.format(row, seat), end=' ')  # format outputs with space 
        seat = chr(ord(seat) + 1)   # convert character to integer and increment 
    row = (row +1)   # increment
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())


i = 1
for row in range(num_rows):
    j = 'A'
    for col in range(num_cols):
    print(f'{i}{j}', end=' ') # Print before incrementing letter2.
    j = chr(ord(j) + 1)
i = i + 1 # only runs after the inner loop is done to increment letter1 for the next loop.
print()
```

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70886648/3216427. except with the indentation done wrong. Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from taking a snippet from @vash_the_stampede and some code from @Martin Tovmassian over on a post about how to find letters in a range.

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

rows = num_rows
columns = num_cols
from string import ascii_letters

def range_alpha(start_letter, end_letter):
  return ascii_letters[
    ascii_letters.index(start_letter):ascii_letters.index(end_letter) + 1
  ]
l = (range_alpha('A', 'Z'))

for i in range(1, rows +1):
    for j in range(1, columns + 1):
        print('{}{} '.format(i, l[j-1]), end='')

columns = 0
print()
```

I hope this helps someone trying to figure it out.  I know this could be cleaner but I'm still in the middle of learning the basics of programming in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using for loops, this way in my opinion is easier

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

letter = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
l = letter.split(" ")

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(num_cols):
        print(f'{i+1}{l[j]}', end = " ")

print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

rows = 1
while rows <= num_rows:
    seat_letter = 'A'
    for j in range(num_cols):
        print("{}{}".format(rows, seat_letter),end=' ')
        seat_letter = chr(ord(seat_letter) + 1)
    rows += 1
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

row = 1 
cols = '?'
while row <= num_rows:  
    cols = 'A'
    while cols < chr(ord('A') + num_cols):  
        print(f'{row}{cols}', end = ' ')
        cols = chr(ord(cols) + 1)
    row = row + 1
```

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone doing 3.12.3 Nested loops: Print seats on Zybooks specifically, this is an answer that works(based on another user's answer with a slight correction in formatting).

Source: I input it on Zybooks and it accepted the answer as correct.

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

# Note 1: You will need to declare more variables
# Note 2: Place end=' ' at the end of your print statement to separate seats by spaces

letter = "A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z"
l = letter.split(" ")

for i in range(num_rows):
    for j in range(num_cols):
        print(f'{i + 1}{l[j]}', end = " ")

print()
```

Answer (score 0):

This was how I was able to do it in the most simple way possible.

```
    num_rows = int(input())
    num_cols = int(input())

    row = 1
    col = 65

    while row <= num_rows:
        col = 65
        while col <= (num_cols + 64):
            print('{}{}'.format(row, chr(col)), end= ' ')
            col += 1
        row += 1   
    print()
```

By using chr() I was able to convert the int input (which zybooks doesn't let you alter) to get the ascii code for uppercase A. You have to use uppercase letters and you have to leave spaces at the end of each pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one, the way that he ask the question is incorrect, zybooks will take this one.`

```
num_rows = int(input())
num_cols = int(input())

for curr_row in range(num_rows):
    curr_col_let = 'A'
    curr_row += 1
    for curr_cols in range(num_cols):
        print (f'{curr_row}{curr_col_let}', end=' ')
        curr_col_let = chr(ord(curr_col_let) + 1)
    print()
```

Answer (score -3):

```
s1 = 1
while s1 <= num_rows and num_cols != 0:
    s2 = 'A'
    while s2 <= 'C':
        print('%s%s' % (s1,s2), end = ' ')
        s2 = chr(ord(s2) + 1)
s1 += 1
```

print()

Comment: Please explain how this answer solves the problem or adds value to this question